# Fully cursive font selection help

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I am trying to 3D print some names for a wedding and I'm trying to make them all the same font. The issue I am having is that the cursive font that I have chosen ([Milkshake](https://www.boldfacedgoods.com/products/milkshake)) looks cursive but does not join up all the letters for all names. Here is an example:

[image]

I am trying to find a similar-ish cursive font that does join up all the letters all the time. Can you please help me find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a white thick stroke like a sticker it's the best solution, with this you can use the font you want.

[image: Sticker]

Using negative tracking you must edit each case:

[image: negative tracking]

Finding a font with this special characteristic in syllables like T+LC-vowel, P+LC-vowel, V+LC-vowel, W+LC-vowel, will produce a very strange specimen like:

[Americana Dream](https://www.dafont.com/sf-americana-dreams.font?text=Si%20To%20Pe%20Va%20Wu&psize=l) via dafont.com

[image: Americana]

Or some calligraphic font like:

[Pinocchio Scribe Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/trueblue/pinocchio/scribe-regular/) via myfonts.com

[image]